# Prove that the circuit rank $= |e|-|v|+c$ , where $c$ is the number of connected components?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How to prove that for any given graph $G=(V,E)$, 
the circuit rank is $$|E|- |V| + C,$$
Where $C$ is the number of connected components.

Comment: Could you do it if $C=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, we need to delete edges such that each connected component turns into a tree.  We know that an $n$-vertex tree has $n-1$ edges, and, more generally, an $|V|$-vertex $C$-component forest (the union of $C$ trees) has $|V|-C$ edges ([ref.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Forest.html)).

So the minimum number of edges that must be deleted to create an acyclic subgraph is $|E|-(|V|-C)=|E|-|V|+C$, the circuit rank.